# Launch image is not working properly for Landscape mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, splash-screen

We have created an application for both iPhone and iPad devices. We are supporting only portrait.

I have a problem with Launch image.If we keep device(Only for iPad) in portrait it is working properly and it is showing portrait launch image.

But if we keep device(Only for iPad) in landscape and run the app, it is showing launch image for few milli seconds then it is showing blue(purple) screen. This is happening only for iPads.

I added images for iPad portrait, as Default-portrait.png, and Default-portrait@2x.png for both 1x and 2x respectively(iPad landscape is unchecked).

Then I tried of adding landscape(checked landscape images option) images for iPads but no use.

Can anyone tell me what is the exact problem here and how to resolve.(we are supporting iOS 8 and above)

Comment: Is your app an universal app (see XCode, General, Deployment Info, Devices), i.e. supposed to run with the full iPad screen, or is it an iPhone only app that runs with the restricted screen simulating an iPhone?

Comment: Thanks for the replay, and yeah it is a universal app. While debugging, it is showing launch image, till didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in app delegate, then it is showing blue screen for few milli seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my leader(he fixed the same problem), go to **plist** file:

- Find the item **Supported interface orientations (iPad)**
- With its children: Just keep **Portrait (bottom home button)**, delete others.

Comment: @Wills-In It means your app just supports iPad Portrait. It always appears in Portrait mode.